# Recurrence Analysis for unevenly spaced time series

Tags: time-series, unevenly-spaced-time-series

Recurrence Analysis requires even time sampling.
Is there a workaround to apply this technique to unevenly spaced data?

Comment: As long as you know the spacing between your data points, you can interpolate/resample to obtain an "even time sampling."

Comment: @OpenSeason without changing the results of the recurrence analysis?

Comment: I agree with Gavin, I would avoid interpolating ...

Comment: A possible approach is to use a Markov model with sacrificing of a few points after a gap so that you have enough lags to predict the next sequence, depending on the order of the Markov process.  E.g. for a first-order Markov process if there is a gap of 5 time periods, the next measurement can be used as a lagged value of the measurement after that but cannot be easily used as a response value itself.